# How do I get blueprints?

Tags: kittens-game

I got 2 blueprints I only don't know how I got them. I know how I can use them, for different building.

My guess is that I get them from sending Hunters.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Blueprints can be crafted at the Workshop once you have the right technologies, but they cost a lot of science and culture to make (indirectly, through their requirements).

The other way to get blueprints, which probably happened to you, is through trading; every trade has a 10% chance to give a single blueprint.

Comment: Trading is by far the simplest way to get them, as crafting takes Furs --> Parchment --> Manuscripts --> Compendiums --> Blueprints.  It adds up super quickly.

Comment: Does that 10% increase or decrease with the attitude of the "animal" I am trading with?

Comment: @Frank When you get Offset Printing at the workshop, so your steamworks are printing manuscripts quite quickly, the bottleneck of culture usually not having a high cap goes away somewhat, and crafting gets more feasible. Especially with the CAD upgrade, since that makes all science buildings give a bonus to blueprint crafting.

Comment: @Damek It's always 10%, though if a hostile race refuses to trade at all, then it never even tries to check for blueprints this trade. See [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/184416/50582) for more.

Comment: I get all my blueprints through my [trades with the Zebras](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/185038/1413).